# animate out image on click function while overlapping its sibling elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First time user and in need of help.

I have three `li li li` elements, each has their own `<img>` inside it. I would like to **animate** the individual `<img>` inside outwards while overlapping other sibling elements (in this expanding effect, the siblings shouldn't be moving,)when the selected element is clicked.

The HTML markup i have:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <ul>
     <li class="card">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="some-img.jpg">
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="card">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="some-img.jpg">
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="card">
        <div class="content">
          <img src="some-img.jpg">
        </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS Markup:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 28%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2.5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -50%;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.card').on('click','.content',function(){
  $(this).css({
     'position':'fixed',
     'z-index':'10'          
  });
});
```

I've done different iterations of this code back and forth, but setting the position of the `.content` to fixed does somewhat close to what i'm trying to do, it overlaps the other siblings... but without any smooth transitions flowing outwards.

Here is a link to the code in codepen: http://codepen.io/broham89/pen/WrJmyB

I **very very** much appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` and `position` are not technically animatable properties, so whatever solution would have to be a little hacky. You can accomplish this by fiddling with CSS classes and jQuery toggle. I changed the code a bit so the primary animation/transition occurs on the parent `li` rather than the `.content` element. In order for all three `li`s to remain in the same position, I changed them to absolutely positioned elements with different `:nth-child` positioning declarations and gave the `ul` a `position` of `relative`. Currently, it's designed around three elements, but you can play around with the values if you need more (or use JS to determine the math).

The jQuery code here toggles `.cardhover` class which moves the element to `left` position of `0` -- the start of the `ul` container -- to prevent any overflow. And it also adds `.cardactive` for `z-index` which makes sure that the element is on top of other elements during the bigger/smaller transitions. (And it removes the class from any other siblings at the beginning.)

https://jsfiddle.net/nn454trm/11/

```js
    $('.card').on('click', '.content', function() {
    
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('cardactive'); 
$(this).parent().addClass('cardactive').toggleClass('cardhover');
      });
```

```css
ul {
  position: relative;

}

.card {

  position: absolute;
  width: 28%;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 2s;
  margin: 2.5%;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.card:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
  left: 33.3%;
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  left: 66.66%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}


.cardhover {
  width: 95%;

  left: 0% !important;
}
.cardactive {
  z-index: 20;
 background: blue; //for demo purposes
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="card">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="some-img.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="some-img.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="some-img.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah that also was what i initially did in the beginning, setting the `li` still with left positioning. But i thought it that wasn't a good way doing that. If there isn't a better way then ill just use it. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

For smooth transitions, don't you want `animate` instead of `css`?

http://api.jquery.com/animate/